# Open port on TPlink c3200 connected to bridged ISP router

Tags: networking, router, ip

I need to connect an alarm system by wire to ny internet connection. I have a router put in bridge mode subsequently connected to a TPlink c3200 router. If I connect the alarmsystem to port1 in the bridged router it works (the other ports are only for TV in bridge mode), but then I dont have internet connection.

Thus, I´d like to connect the alarmsystem to the TPlink router. I have the MAC adress of the device and it needs port 6375 under UDP protocol. However, it does not show up under the wired clients. I tried setting up static IP for the MAC adress both under DHCP server tab in the web-interface, but also under the security-tab --> IP and MAC binding tab. The assigned static IP adress was then used as the internal IP under virtual servers and I opened port 6375 both internally and externally under UDP protocol. However, I does not help. Any suggestions?

Image of the port-opening:
[image]

Images of assigning static IP to the MAC adress: 
Dont know if they are both required.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The comments associated with this question can be found [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76692/discussion-on-question-by-misha-open-port-on-tplink-c3200-connected-to-bridged-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question:

The alarm system was holding on to an old address on its network interface.
When dealing with network configuration changes on embedded systems, its a good idea to power cycle the device. (alarm systems, DVR's, IP-cameras, TV's) this holds especially true with devices that have no display, or user control for the network adapter settings. these types of devices usually request a new DHCP address on boot.

Things to check, if you are having trouble with a device like this:

If you are trying to port-forward to the device. Check your routers WAN IP address, make sure you have a publicly routable address. Not a private address space, like 10.x.x.x , 172.16.x.x or 192.168.1.x etc. If your WAN connection is a Private IP address it most likely means you are behind **Carrier Grade NAT.**

Do you know the IP of the device?
if it doesn't show up in the routers DHCP lease list.
you can run "arp -a" from the command prompt. this will give you a list of MAC-IP pairs on the LAN.

Additionally you can use the program Nmap to scan your local IP range using,
"nmap -sL -n 192.168.1.0/24" (replace the network with your subnet in use.)

Finally you can test network connectivity to the device in question with the ping command from the command promt. example: Ping 192.168.1.27

Comment: ...And then I did a reset of my router and the alarm system is off the grid again despite 5 hours of subsequent troubleshooting..

Comment: arp -a gives ? (192.168.1.64) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]. However, I tried setting up ..64 up with port 6375 open. But to no help.

Comment: Nope--I have no idea what the 'at incomplete' means. And the security company is blaming my internet provider and vica verca.

Comment: Is the routers admin gui showing the device as having a lease? Is it unreachable via ping on the address you found it assigned? I would place the Blame on the device itself, as you know it already did work with your internet connection...

Comment: No--The gui did not show a lease and it was unreachable via ping. Now, I cant even find it again using arp -a

Comment: Yep--many times. Thing is - the battery kicks in and I doubt I get a true restart..

Comment: That's a problem... Can you remove it?

Comment: I guess I have to ask the security guys.. But it is strange that it works immediately when connected to the bridged router (leaving me without internet), but not when I forward the ports.

Comment: I agree it's strange. Have you tried a different network IP scheme? It seems odd it would get a global address ok, but not a private one. Try changing your network to 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0, put the router at 10.10.10.1 DHCP range = 10.10.10.10 to 10.10.10.20 (the smaller range is just for easy troubleshooting) you can change it to a larger one if it works. Make sure you refresh any network adapters after so you aren't holding old DHCP info on them.

Comment: The router is refusing: LAN ports Ip cannot match the subnet mask.

Comment: You may be entering it wrong. Or maybe I haven't articluated correctly. But tp-link routers definitely can have this network range.

Comment: Got in touch with the security company today again. All of sudden they realized they could change a setting and now it works perfectly....Should  charge they by the hour. Thanks for your help. learnt a lot.